# What happens if you modify a image when it's open?

Tags: png

I was doing a geometry dash private server with a friend then I noticed that we can modify images in ftp while someone is running the game so I want to ask what will happen if we rename the image when someone is playing?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what image you're talking about. Gamesheets get loaded on starting the game so renaming them will do nothing while running the game but detail images like the vault faces will only be loaded when needed. Since the names of these images are hardcoded you need to change those before renaming them, otherwise it will just crash due to missing files.